# Java 8 extension methods - why are they not called mixins or traits?

Tags: java, mixins, traits, java-8

As far as I know, Groovy already has mixins, Scala has traits. C family has multiple inheritance. So why is the new functionality in Java called "extension methods"? Is it just a different name for the same thing, or was there another reason? What are the differences from traits and mixins? what do they add and what do they lack?

---

Personaly I see them more as "implementation methods" than "extension methods".

Comment: One big difference is that interfaces can't have instance fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So why is the new functionality in Java called "extension methods"?

AFAIK, This naming come from C#.  Virtual extension methods are only for methods whereas mixins and traits apply to fields as well.

[Interface evolution via virtual extension methods](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/Defender%20Methods%20v4.pdf)  Note: Brian himself calls them "Defender methods" but I suppose "Virtual extension methods" is more widely recognised.

[JVM Language Summit 2011 - Brian Goetz](http://arhipov.blogspot.com/2011/08/jvm-language-summit-2011-brian-goetz_31.html) I am pretty sure this is where he talks about why it has the name it does.

Comment: Well, actually mixins give both behaviour and state inheritance, while traits give behaviour only. 
I know, Scala has 'Traits' and they got state inheritance... but to be precise those are mixin.